# RetrofitException: Expected URL scheme 'http' or 'https' but no colon was found

Tags: android, retrofit2, rx-android, android-jobscheduler

**Running a Job scheduler to do a retrofit call every 1 minute**

When App is in background able to make the call without exception, but when app is closed & scheduler triggered to make a retrofit call getting Exception.
I could find the baseUrl & interceptors on retrofit object.

After scheduler is triggered will get callback to Receiver.
I'm making a call from receiver using AsyncTask.

```
SaveApiService service = application.retrofit.getRetrofit().create(SaveApiService.class);
*the objects which are injected in Application*

Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
*filling input params here*

Observable<Response> call = service.save(map);
*service with @POST & @QueryMap as input params*

call.subscribe(new Observer<BaseResponse>() {
                @Override
                public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onNext(BaseResponse baseResponse) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable e) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onComplete() {

                }
            });
```

Getting call back to onError with exception.

*Any help will be appreciated*

Comment: Did you check your url, and do you sure that it start with `http://` or `https://`

Comment: Can you provide the code you implemented for this?

Comment: add a logging interceptor to see what your request is actually doing

Comment: then you have to dispose your RxJava Observers when app close.

Comment: @HelloWorld I checked the URL, it's having https://